# How can I increase a value of a column based on another column's value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am a newbie to SQL. I have a pretty noob question, working on a seo stuff, I want to know how can I increase the rank number of a column based on the hits from another column.

For example if the hits goes to 10 the rank increase by 1 and on next 10 hits it again increases by one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like there is a very simple mathematical relationship betwee `rank` and `hits`:

```
UPDATE foo SET rank = FLOOR(hits/10);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to update `rank` each time by yourself, you can use [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

You can add it to your table like that :

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD rank AS FLOOR(hits/10);
```